# Xcode project crashes on load

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to get my build on iOS for the past 3 days to no avail. I have tried everything i have read with tonnes of research into this issue and still nothing so now i am asking you guys if you can help. This is built via Unity3D

My developer who does everything iOS is on holiday in paris, so their is no internal support for this issue either.

The app will just crash upon building and putting on device. This is the error log.

```
    2016-11-15 16:38:15.395 digital[639:115676] -> registered mono modules 0x1013cac00
 -> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
 -> applicationDidBecomeActive()
 GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
 Init: screen size 2048x1536
 Initializing Metal device caps: Apple A7 GPU
 Initialize engine version: 5.4.2f2 (b7e030c65c9b)
 OnLevelWasLoaded was found on DOTweenComponent
 This message has been deprecated and will be removed in a later version of Unity.
 Add a delegate to SceneManager.sceneLoaded instead to get notifications after scene loading has completed

 (Filename:  Line: 375)

 The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '1x4(Clone)') is missing!

 (Filename:  Line: 1656)

 The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'OneByThree') is missing!

 (Filename:  Line: 1656)

 The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'BokehController') is missing!

 (Filename:  Line: 1656)

 The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'BokehField') is missing!

 (Filename:  Line: 1656)

 The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'BokehField') is missing!

 (Filename:  Line: 1656)

 The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'BokehField') is missing!

 (Filename:  Line: 1656)

 The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'BokehField') is missing!

 (Filename:  Line: 1656)

 The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'New PAParticleField') is missing!

 (Filename:  Line: 1656)

 The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'New PAParticleField') is missing!

 (Filename:  Line: 1656)

 The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'BokehController') is missing!

 (Filename:  Line: 1656)

 UnloadTime: 44.684330 ms
 2016-11-15 16:38:25.911 digital[639:115676] -[NSTaggedPointerString al_containsSubstring:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0045564954414e6
 2016-11-15 16:38:25.918 digital[639:115676] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString al_containsSubstring:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0045564954414e6'
 *** First throw call stack:
 (0x182e1adb0 0x18247ff80 0x182e21c4c 0x182e1ebec 0x182d1cc5c 0x101213048 0x101210f40 0x10120fd5c 0x10120fae4 0x10008f458 0x1008aacf8 0x1011d418c 0x100a9e53c 0x100a9e90c 0x100a91c8c 0x100a939ec 0x100a93ce0 0x100a93958 0x100ab9b94 0x100ab9ab4 0x100ab9a48 0x100a9dc64 0x100a9dcb0 0x100a9d830 0x100a9d8f4 0x100a9d620 0x100a99660 0x100a99a68 0x1009906d4 0x100a56d2c 0x100cef1e0 0x100086960 0x1837e2658 0x182dd1794 0x182dd1438 0x182dceb4c 0x182cf8c50 0x1845e0088 0x187fda088 0x100072fac 0x1828968b8)
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
 (lldb)
```

And here is the screen shot of what is happening on Xcode

[image: XCODE]

Comment: It says that referenced scripts are missing. Check that. Also the image is saying SIGABRT. Search why that error occurs. For a start, check if all your outlets, buttons, labels etc have proper connections.

Comment: This is the problem: "[NSTaggedPointerString al_containsSubstring:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance". It means a method called al_containsSubstring is being called on an instance of the class NSTaggedPointerString but that class does not have a method with that name.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, Yash Tamakuwala The game is packaged in unity so all buttons etc should be fine i believe. As for Referenced Scripts i will do that now, never thought it was important as it never affected previous builds.



@Essenceofchickens

Thank you for this explanation, but when i try to search for this class within Xcode it tells me their is no results for it : ( Or do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: NSTaggedPointerString is a standard class. Search in the code for al_containsSubstring. Your developer is maybe trying to call al_containsSubstring on his own class and is calling it on a NSTaggedPointerString by mistake.

Comment: @Essenceofchickens Honestly thanks for still trying to help me out, really appreciate it. Again i have searched through the code and it is saying it cannot find it. I Develop in unity and C-sharp and am feeling a little silly right now. As for the developer calling al_containsSubstring, i don't think he is as again we do not do anything code wise within Xcode, its all Unity3D so im not sure how this could even occur?

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about Unity. When searching make sure you are have case sensitive search turned off, or make sure you type the search term in the correct case.

Comment: Going to try and rebuild in Unity again just to be sure its working how it is meant to. Again mate thank you for your help mate.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Linker Flags in Build Settings.

The -ObjC flag must be added for static libraries to run correctly.